# Como enviar mensagens usando Angular e socket.io?

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

Segui os passos desse [vídeo](http:///https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHbCkikFfDE) e consegui fazer um web app de envio de mensagens.
Agora, estou tentando implementar esses códigos no meu app de mensagens em Ionic.
Mas ao tentar enviar uma mensagem, esse aviso fica aparecendo, em looping, no console do chrome:

> "socket.io.js:4194 GET http://localhost:8888/socket.io/?

Segue meu script do controller que envia a mensagem:

```
$scope.enviarMsg = function (mensagem) {
    $scope.disableButton = true;
    var socket = io.connect();

    var dia = moment().format(); //2016-02-16 T 16:05:52-02:00
    var diaP = dia.split('T');
    var dia = diaP[0];

    var horaP = diaP[1];
    var horaP2 = horaP.split(':');
    var hora = horaP2[0]+':'+horaP2[1];
    //console.log(mensagem['msg']);

    var mensagem = mensagem['msg'];
    var idUsuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario');
    var idCep = $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep');
    var nome = $window.localStorage.getItem('nome');
    var usuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('usuario');
    var uf = $window.localStorage.getItem('estado');
    var cidade = $window.localStorage.getItem('cidade');
    var bairro = $window.localStorage.getItem('bairro');
    var logradouro = $window.localStorage.getItem('logradouro');
    var dia = dia;
    var hora = hora;

    var dadosMensagem = {
            "mensagem": mensagem,
            "idUsuario": idUsuario,
            "idCep": idCep,
            "usuario": usuario,
            "uf": uf,
            "cidade": cidade,
            "bairro": bairro,
            "logradouro": logradouro,
            "dia": dia,
            "hora": hora
        };

    console.log(dadosMensagem);

    socket.emit('send message', dadosMensagem);

   }
```